# BrowserMobProxy doesn't capture any entries into har file

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

Trying to capture http headers on some test page `localhost:8000` and HAR file doesn't seem to contain anything in `entry` section.

My code:

```
            BrowserMobProxyServer proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();

            proxy.start(0);
            Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);
            seleniumProxy.setSslProxy("trustAllSSLCertificates");
            try {
                String hostIp = Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
                seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(hostIp + ":" + proxy.getPort());
                seleniumProxy.setSslProxy(hostIp + ":" + proxy.getPort());
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            DesiredCapabilities seleniumCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
            seleniumCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.SUPPORTS_JAVASCRIPT, true);

            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=temp");
            options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
            options.merge(seleniumCapabilities);
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

            proxy.setHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_HEADERS, CaptureType.RESPONSE_HEADERS);
            proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_HEADERS,CaptureType.RESPONSE_HEADERS);
            proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);
            driver.get("http://localhost:8000")
            proxy.newHar("Test");
```

By the time `http://localhost:8000` opens I can see 8 items in `console>networks` tab
However har file is:

```
{"log":{"version":"1.2","creator":{"name":"BrowserMob Proxy","version":"2.1.4","comment":""},"pages":[{"id":"Test","startedDateTime":"2019-09-16T11:06:02.020Z","title":"Test","pageTimings":{"comment":""},"comment":""}],"entries":[],"comment":""}}
```

Digged through zillion pages, it looks like all other folks only have problem with http and headless.

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.
Changing String hostIp = "localhost" did fix the issue.